# CameraX is not launching the camera

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm a noob. I'm trying to implement a simple features where the user captures an image on android app and then sends it to server. But, i'm unable to launch the camera with the following code.

```
package com.example.scanner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio;
import androidx.camera.core.Camera;
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException;
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy;
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Runnable {
    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View button = findViewById(R.id.button_camera);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public static void checkCameraPermissions(Context context){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Permission is not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA },
                    100);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        checkCameraPermissions(this);
        instance = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        instance.addListener(this, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA;
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().setFlashMode(ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
                .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3).build();
        imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image);
                System.out.println("Image captured");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                super.onError(exception);
                System.out.println("Image capture error");
            }
        });
        try {
            instance.get().unbindAll();
            Camera camera = instance.get().bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageCapture);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Logs

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 0
I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED
D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 1
I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL
D/CameraValidator: Verifying camera lens facing on generic_x86, lensFacingInteger: null
D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=1, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@b594e82}
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950 ACTIVE
I/System.out: Image capture error
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Use cases [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950] now ATTACHED
D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950] for camera: 1
D/MeteringRepeating: MeteringSession SurfaceTexture size: 640x480
D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@771480b}
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950, MeteringRepeating140716966] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Resetting Capture Session
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Releasing session in state INITIALIZED
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Attempting to force open the camera.
D/CameraStateRegistry: tryOpenCamera(Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]) [Available Cameras: 1, Already Open: false (Previous state: null)] --> SUCCESS
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@ff47ced[id=0]                         UNKNOWN               
    Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]                         OPENING               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Opening camera.
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Transitioning camera internal state: INITIALIZED --> OPENING
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null
    Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950, MeteringRepeating140716966] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Use case androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950 ACTIVE
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950, MeteringRepeating140716966] for camera: 1
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} CameraDevice.onOpened()
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> OPENED
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@ff47ced[id=0]                         UNKNOWN               
    Camera@f05aa9c[id=1]                         OPEN                  
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null
D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950, MeteringRepeating140716966] for camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-13259d05-6a33-46c4-a2da-b6445df075d450632950, MeteringRepeating140716966] for camera: 1
D/SyncCaptureSessionBase: [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@96849fb] getSurface...done
D/CaptureSession: Opening capture session.
D/DeferrableSurface: New surface in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@b594e82}
    use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@b594e82
    New surface in use[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@771480b}
D/DeferrableSurface: use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@771480b
D/CaptureSession: Attempting to send capture request onConfigured
D/CaptureSession: Issuing request for session.
W/Gralloc4: allocator 3.x is not supported
D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onConfigured() mState=OPENED
D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onReady() OPENED
```

Could someone point me where i'm doing wrong. I am a noob.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue??

Comment: @manoj Turns out, i cannot test the camera function from the simulator. I need to debug it on the phone to test this functionality.